# Kohana Routing (and Rerouting) Issue

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I am using PHP 5.5 and Kohana 3.3

I am developing a website structure that always has the language preference of the user as the first "item" of a uri.

For example:

`mydomain.com/en/products`
`mydomain.com/de/store`

Now, I am sure that some users will try and be clever and type things in like:

`mydomain.com/products`

which is fine, I just would like them to be rerouted to

`mydomain.com/en/products` to keep everything consistent.

The code I have below is working as long as the uri has only one "directory" in the URI e.g.

`mydomain.com/products`

`mydomain.com/store`

but not for uris like down further subdirectories like:

`mydomain.com/products/something`
`mydomain.com/store/purchase/info`

Here are my routes:

```
Route::set('home_page', '(<lang>)')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'Index'
    ));

Route::set('default', '(<lang>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<subfolder>))))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'Index',
        'action' => 'index'
    ));
```

Here is the code in my parent controller that every other controller inherits from:

```
public function before()
        {           
            $this->uri = $this->request->uri();

            $this->lang = $this->request->param('lang');

            //If user directly inputted url mydomain.com without language information, redirect them to language version of site
            //TODO use cookie information to guess language preferences if possible
            if(!isset($this->lang))
            {
                $this->redirect('en/', 302);
            }

            //If the first part of path does not match a language redirect to english version of uri
            if(!in_array($this->lang, ContentManager::getSupportedLangs()))
            {
                $this->redirect('en/'.$this->uri, 302);
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the two routes given with this one:

```
Route::set('default', '(<lang>/)(<controller>(/<action>(/<subfolder>)))',
array(
    'lang' => '(en|fr|pl)'
))
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'Index',
    'action' => 'index'
));
```

where the string (en|fr|pl) is the concatenation of your supported languages, i.e. `'('.implode('|', ContentManager::getSupportedLangs()).')'`.

If this solution remains obscure I'm happy to explain it in more detail but I hope you can see on reflection that your problem arose because your **first** route, `home_page`, was being matched by e.g. `mydomain.com/products`.

Your controllers' `before()` function should be revised as well.  The redirects won't work as things stand because you're going to end up redirecting to e.g. `en/ru/Index`.  So why not keep it simple and use:

```
    public function before()
    {           
        $default_lang = 'en';
        $this->lang = $this->request->param('lang', $default_lang);
    }
```

Comment: Won't this deliver a 404 though when the user does not specify a lang in the url (en, fr, or pl)? I want to take the url `/products/something` and route them to `/en/products/something`. I want the users to be completely unaware of the fact that they must specify a language in the url if they punch in an address in their address bar

Comment: No it won't deliver a 404: try it!  The reason is that the parentheses in `(<lang>/)` in the route make that part optional.  So if no match is found using of the supported languages, it will treat it as if it were not there.

Comment: Well of course you were correct. Sorry I just got around to trying it out now. Thanks so much for your advice.